# finding derivative of g(x) = xtanx

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

The question reads if $g(x) = x\tan x$, then the value of $g'\left(\frac\pi4\right)$ is:

a) $1+ \frac\pi4$

b) $\frac\pi2-2$

c) $1-\frac\pi4$

d) $1+\frac\pi2$

I can never get to a situation where I have all trig functions out of the derivative as is shown in any of the answers

Comment: What did you get $g'(x)$ out of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note;
\begin{equation}
g'(x)=\tan x + x \sec^{2}x
\end{equation}
At $\pi/4$
\begin{eqnarray}
g'(\pi/4) &=& \tan \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4} \sec^{2} \frac{\pi}{4}\\
          &=& 1+ \frac{\pi}{4} \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{2}\\
          &=& 1+\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

First, calculate $g'(x)$ for a general value of $x$. For that, write down $g$ as a product of two functions you know how to differentiate:

$$g(x)=f(x)\cdot h(x)$$

This part should be easy as the choice of $f$ and $h$ is quite apparent.

Then use the product rule:

$$g'(x) = f'(x)h(x) + f(x)h'(x)$$

Then, once you have $g'(x)$, just plug in $x=\frac\pi4$.

---

Try to use my hint and see how far you get. If you are still stuck, then edit your question with your progress (or comment on this question) and I (we) will attempt to help you further.

Comment: Thanks. The hint helped. But I realised that my problem was mainly to do with not knowing my trig identities well enough. Like if f(x) = tanx, then f'(x) = sec^2x and so on

Comment: @Sadio $\tan x = \sec^2 x?$ You probably mean $\tan' x = \sec^2 x$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, got a little confused. edited comment. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$g'(x)=\tan{x}+x(1+\tan^2{x})$$

so $g'(\frac{\pi}{4})=1+\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$g(x)=x\tan x$$
$$g'(x)=\tan x+\frac{x}{\sin^2x}$$
$$g'(\pi/4)=\tan(\pi/4)+\frac{\pi/4}{\sin^2(\pi/4)}=1+\frac{\pi}{4(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})^2}=1+\pi/2$$